# Filtros por campos y fechas

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Realizo un formulario en el cual muestro los registros de los inmuebles que dieron de alta cada una de las inmobiliarias. Debe de limitarse a que solo vea sus propios inmuebles (por el campo **inmobiliaria_inmobiliaria**), en este caso es el ID 7. Coloco la condición y efectivamente solo me muestra los que dio de alta la inmobiliaria, pero al realizar el filtro por **estatus_id, kind_id, priority_id** y por las fechas **start_at** y **finish_at**, realiza una búsqueda general en toda la tabla y no respeta la condición: en este caso solo tendría que buscar por esos campos con el ID de la inmobiliaria.

[image: INTERFAZ FILTROS]

[image: CODIGO]

```php
<?php
    $users = [];
    if (
        !empty($_GET["estatus_id"])
        || !empty($_GET["kind_id"])
        || !empty($_GET["priority_id"])
        || !empty($_GET["start_at"])
        || !empty($_GET["finish_at"])
    ) {
        $sql = "select * from v_cita_completo ";
        $where = [];
        if (!empty(["estatus_id"])) {
            $where[] = "estatus_id = '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET["estatus_id"]) ."'";
        }

        if (!empty(["kind_id"])) {
            $where[] = "kind_id = '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET["kind_id"]) . "'";
        }


        if (!empty($_GET["priority_id"])) {
            $where[] = " priority_id = '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET["priority_id"]) . "'";
        }



        if (!empty($_GET["start_at"]) && !empty($_GET["finish_at"])) {
            $where[] = "created_at BETWEEN '"
                . mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET["start_at"])
                . " 00:00:00' AND '"
                . mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET["finish_at"])
                . " 23:59:59'"
            ;
        }
        if (count($where) > 0) {
            $sql .= ' WHERE ' . implode(' AND ', $where);
        }
        $users = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

    } else {
        $users = mysqli_query($con, "select * from v_cita_completo  where inmobiliaria_inmobiliaria = 7");
    }
    if ($users === false) {
        die('Error SQL: ' . mysqli_error($con));
    }

    if(@mysqli_num_rows($users)>0){
        // si hay reportes
        $_SESSION["report_data"] = $users;
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solo debes cambiar este bloque de código:

```
if (count($where) > 0) {
    $sql .= ' WHERE ' . implode(' AND ', $where);
}
```

Para forzar siempre la inmobiliaria:

```
// Inicializar filtro con inmobiliaria
$sql .= ' WHERE inmobiliaria = 7';
if(count($where) > 0) {
    // Aquí agregas el resto de filtros
    $sql .= ' AND ' . implode(' AND ', $where);
}
```

Comment: muchas gracias por tu ayuda.